# How do I specify structure of all child elements of a node in XSD where the node names vary?

Tags: configuration, xml

I am building Magento 1 XSDs (XML Schema Definitions). Magento very often uses node names as a unique identifier for a node in XML.

For example:

```
<config>
    <events>
        <log_log_clean_after>
            <observers>
                <catalog_product_compare_item>
                    <class>catalog/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductCompareClean</method>
                </catalog_product_compare_item>
            </observers>
        </log_log_clean_after>
        <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
            <observers>
                <catalog_add_topmenu_items>
                    <class>catalog/observer</class>
                    <method>addCatalogToTopmenuItems</method>
                </catalog_add_topmenu_items>
            </observers>
        </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
        <catalog_entity_attribute_save_before>
            <observers>
                <catalog_check_reserved_attribute_codes>
                    <class>catalog/observer</class>
                    <method>checkReservedAttributeCodes</method>
                </catalog_check_reserved_attribute_codes>
            </observers>
        </catalog_entity_attribute_save_before>
    </events>
</config>
```

I know the structure of each node within the "events" node should have an "observers" which should contain observer definitions. And I know that an observer definition should have the structure of always containing one "class" node and one "method" node.

How do I specify this in an XSD? I have not been able to figure out how to specify structure for varied named nodes.